# Excel file corrupted during write

Tags: java, jxl, jexcelapi

Whenever i try to manipulate an excel file,the corresponding excel file gets corrupted.
Please give suggestion of how to tackle this thing. I have written the code in java.

Here is the code:

```
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("book.xls"));
WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(newFile(""), workbook);
WritableSheet sheet = copy.getSheet(0);
WritableFont times16font = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 20, WritableFont.BOLD); WritableCellFormat times16format = new WritableCellFormat (times16font);
Label label = new Label(3, 4, "Good", times16format);
sheet.addCell(label);
Label label1 = new Label(3, 5, "Good", times16format);
heet.addCell(label);
copy.write();
copy.close();
```

Comment: Posting your code would be a good starting to tackling this

Comment: You'll need to provide *way* more information on what you're doing and how you're doing it to get any kind of sensible answer for that problem.

Comment: You should post some of code which manipulates with excel files.

Comment: Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("book.xls"));
    WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(newFile(""), workbook);
    WritableSheet sheet = copy.getSheet(0);
    WritableFont times16font = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 20, WritableFont.BOLD);
    WritableCellFormat times16format = new WritableCellFormat (times16font); 
    Label label = new Label(3, 4, "Good", times16format);
    sheet.addCell(label); 
    Label label1 = new Label(3, 5, "Good", times16format);
    sheet.addCell(label); 
    copy.write();
    copy.close();

Answer (score 0):

The second time you add label to the sheet, it is the same label. I think you meant to add label1.
However, with that said, there's nothing that should produce a corrupt output.